# Random PHP/MySQL query updating every few minutes, not on refresh

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have two tables in a MySQL databases, one of images, one of text:

Table 1 (images):

```
<img src="pngs/000.png">
<img src="pngs/001.png">
<img src="pngs/002.png">
...
<img src="pngs/199.png">
```

Table 2 (text):

```
"This is text 0."
"This is text 1."
"This is text 2."
...
"This is text 1999."
```

I would like the page to display a random image, and ten lines of random text, which update on each access and every refresh.

So far, I have this working perfectly on a local Web Apache server. However, when uploaded online, there are a couple of issues:

1. The results update to new random results every ~five minutes, rather than on each refresh.
2. The results are the same across devices, rather than unique for each instance.

I am currently using the following method to select a random row from the MySQL database:

```
$query  = 'SELECT * FROM pngs ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

And referring to that script in the HTML with:

```
<div class='img'><?php include('pngs.php');?></div>
```

Is the delay in updating the images a problem with this implementation? Or am I misunderstanding the MySQL/PHP infrastructure and should be using Javascript instead?

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to produce the desired functionality.

***EDIT**

Here is the full PHP code for the images.

```
<?php
  require_once 'login2.php';
  $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
  if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

  $query  = "SELECT * FROM pngs ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  if (!$result) die($conn->error);

  $result->data_seek(1);
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo '<img src="/pngs/'.$row['png'].'.png">';

  $result->close();
  $conn->close();
?>
```

PHP script for the strings is similar, except uses

```
$query  = "SELECT txt FROM strings WHERE RAND()<=0.011";
```

as I have read that this is a quicker way to select random rows from a large database.

Comment: Where is your pngs.php code?

Comment: Is Table 1 storing the actual images, or their path (e.g. "pngs/000.png")?

Comment: added full PHP code to original post.

Comment: Table 1 is storing their paths and the necessary code for them to be displayed in HTML: <img></img>